# How to overwrite (or pass) parameters in a recursive function?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm searching for a way to overwrite parameters in a recursive function.

I was writing the code to check whether or not it's a binary search tree and below is the code I wrote.

```
class Node:
    # Constructor to create a new node
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def isItBST(root, prev_value, curr_value):
    """
    Using in order traversal, we check if every node is sorted because if it's a BST,
    then it should be sorted.
    """
    if root is not None:
        isItBST(root.left, prev_value, curr_value)
        curr_value = root.data
        print root.data, "curr: ",curr_value, "prev_value: ",prev_value
        if (prev_value > curr_value ):
            print "wrong!" # return False
        prev_value = curr_value
        isItBST(root.right, prev_value, curr_value)

# Define a tree
root = Node(4)
root.left = Node(2)
root.right = Node(5)
root.left.left = Node(1)
root.left.right = Node(8) # This node violates the BT rule

if (isItBST(root,-999999,root.data))==False:
    print "Is Not BST"
else:
    print "Is a BST"
```

output:

```
## -- End pasted text --
1 curr:  1 prev_value:  -999999
2 curr:  2 prev_value:  -999999
8 curr:  8 prev_value:  2
4 curr:  4 prev_value:  -999999
5 curr:  5 prev_value:  4
Is a BST <== which is WRONG
```

If you run this code, it fails to detect because the parameter `prev_value` of the root doesn't get updated during the recursion. Desirably, I'd like to update the `prev_value` during the recursion so that it could print "wrong!" when the `Node(8)` violates the BT rule.

Your answer doesn't need to be specific to this problem. I would appreciate any kind of general idea to pass parameters in recursion.

Comment: `isItBST()` has no `return` statements, so it never returns `True` or `False`.

Comment: any recursive function must have a terminal condition check which prevents further recurring ... you are missing this test

Comment: @ScottStensland `if root is not None:` is the termination check.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're never returning `True` or `False` to indicate whether it's a BST.

```
def isItBST(root, prev_value, curr_value):
    """
    Using in order traversal, we check if every node is sorted because if it's a BST, then it should be sorted.
    """
    if root is not None:
        if not isItBST(root.left, prev_value, curr_value):
            print "wrong!"
            return False
        curr_value = root.data
        print root.data, "curr: ",curr_value, "prev_value: ",prev_value
        if (prev_value > curr_value ):
            print "wrong!"
            return False
        prev_value = curr_value
        return isItBST(root.right, prev_value, curr_value)
    else:
        return True
```